# Displaying Outlook Formatted Emails on other email clients

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email, thunderbird, gmail

Our company sends emails out to clients from Outlook, which have inline images, tables, and other formatting. They display perfectly on Microsoft email clients, but when displaying in other clients like Thunderbird, Gmail etc, they lose some of their formatting, with headers and images no longer being centered etc, since other clients do not recognise these custom Outlook/MSO classes.

Are there any solutions to disable this Outlook specific formatting when sending these emails out, or any way to convert the Outlook email into regular HTML, so they look the same across most email clients?

Comment: Some things can never be made to appear correctly within other email clients, especially on mobile devices _(they'll override formatting)_ - the Outlook desktop program doesn't even display outlook formatted emails correctly within the Outlook mobile app and vice versa. While I haven't tried it, formatting the emails in actual HTML, with everything being within inline HTML, may work - Outlook formats emails in HTML by default _(unless Format as Rich Text is selected - that may also be something to try)_, but actually specifying inline HTML may force things to display correctly on other clients

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected behavior. And we could refer to this document:

Content in email displays differently when using different email clients (blackbaud.com) https://kb.blackbaud.com/knowledgebase/Article/52033

Each email client renders HTML and CSS differently, which causes the email to look differently in certain providers. HTML emails can appear incorrectly when viewed in some email clients.

Also refer to this part:
The following best practices are proactive ways to manage email design compatibility across different email clients.